# ¿Por qué si el editor de código de fuente no muestra ningun error aun así el código no funciona correctamente?

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python y estoy usando el editor "Visual Studio Code", el ejercicio consiste en que según la nota que obtenga el alumno deberá aparecer en pantalla si está aprobado, desapobrado, excelente, etc. Pero, no importa la nota que ponga siempre sale que no está en el rango (cuando si lo está).

```
nota = 5 

lista1 = [0,1,2]
lista2 = [3,4]
lista3 = [5,6,7]
lista4 = [8,9]


if nota in lista1 == True:
    print("necesita reforzamiento")
    
elif nota in lista2 == True:
    print("desaprobado")
    
elif nota in lista3 == True:
    print("aprobado")
    
elif nota in lista4 == True:
    print("excelente")
    
elif nota == 10:
    print("becado")
    
else:
    print("la nota ingresada no está entre el rango requerido")
```

Comment: El editor de código te muestra los errores sintácticos. Tu código es correcto en ese sentido.

Comment: Al costado de la respuesta hay un check, elije la respuesta que mejor haya encajado con la solución que buscabas y dale click a ese check. Así se marca una respuesta como aceptada y eso ayuda a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.

Comment: Que no muestre errores no significa que el programa vaya a funcionar como esperas. La computadora solo sigue órdenes y te informa cuando no las entiende o no las puede cumplir. No sabe qué estás pensando.

Answer (score 4):

Estas encadenando operaciones

Esto

```
if nota in lista1 == True:
```

Es el equivalente de:

```
if nota in lista1 and lista1 == True:
```

Y `lista1 == True` es `False`

---

Pienso que esto no es lo que buscas, si no que lo requieres es simplemente:

```
if nota in lista1:
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda! me sirvió!

Comment: Sabes acerca de "chaining?" (En Inglés, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/) Pregunté hoy en en inglés Stackoverflow y aprendí que `nota in lista1==True` es lo mismo que `(nota in lista1) and (lista1==True)`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77834781/801894

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Efectivamente desconocía el "chaining", realmente de python se hacer un "hello word" y poco más.  No obstante, creo que dejas de lado las intenciones del OP, él no está intentado realizar un "chaining", él NO quiere comparar `lista1==True`, él quiere que:  `(nota in lista1) == True` por eso si es un problema de precedencia, que se soluciona con paréntesis como todo problema de precedencia

Answer (score 1):

Como entorno integrado, las posibilidades de *Visual Code* depende de las herramientas que hayas instalado a través de sus extensiones. No has comentado qué usas para chequear el código, ni como has configurado el resto de herramientas para desarrollo con python.

Para lo que comentas como "código correcto", se usan herramientas llamadas **"linters"**. Puedes elegir entre unas cuantas (mira en la documentación ["Linting Python in Visual Studio Code"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting)).

Mi recomendación es user [ruff](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charliermarsh.ruff), basta con instalar esta extensión y desactivar el resto de linters y formateadores. Ruff se está convirtiendo en la única herramienta que se necesita para programar en python, y es muy rápida.

Cuando paso ruff por tu código me salen los siguientes errores:

```
ppp.py:9:22: E712 Comparison to `True` should be `cond is True` or `if cond:`
ppp.py:12:24: E712 Comparison to `True` should be `cond is True` or `if cond:`
ppp.py:15:24: E712 Comparison to `True` should be `cond is True` or `if cond:`
ppp.py:18:24: E712 Comparison to `True` should be `cond is True` or `if cond:`
Found 4 errors.
```

Si buscas este error en la [documentación de ruff](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/rules/true-false-comparison/) te explica que la comparación de *singletones* se ha de hacer con el operador `is`, no con igualdades. O usar simplemente `if cond:`.

No es mucho, pero tienes algo por dónde empezar.

Cambia:

```py
if nota in lista1 == True:
    ...
```

simplemente por la segunda sugerancia de ruff:

```py
if nota in lista1:
    ...
```

Funciona. Si queremos usar la otra sugerencia de ruff sería:

```py
if (nota in lista1) is True:
    ...
```

Aquí es necesario poner los paréntesis. Tal como te han dicho, el [orden de precedencia de los operadores](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=precedence#operator-precedence) es importante. Pero no es exáctamente como se comenta...

OJO cuando se encadenan varias comparaciones como en tu código. Encadenar operadores de comparación (`in`, `not in`, `is`, `is not`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `!=`, `==`) equivale a encadenar cada una de las comparaciones individuales usando un `and` lógico.

O sea, cuando haces `nota in lista1 is True` encadenas dos comparaciones: `nota in lista1` y `lista1 is True`. La expresión equivalente será `nota in lista1 and lista1 is True`, expresión que siempre resulta `False` en su segunda comparación.

Más información sobre el encadenamiento de comparaciones en la documentación de python: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Me  fue de mucha ayuda :D